# Set a button to right of backbutton of navigation bar iPad monotouch

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I want to have a uibarbuttonitem in right of back button in navigation bar ( if it is not wrong with apples guide line). I use this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem listButton = new UIBarButtonItem ("List View",UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered ,null);


        //assigning left bar buttons
        this.NavigationItem .LeftBarButtonItems =
        new UIBarButtonItem[] { this.NavigationItem .BackBarButtonItem   ,listButton }  ;
```

But `this.NavigationItem .BackBarButtonItem` always is null. What solution is right for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct implement the same :

```
UIButton *leftButtonIcon = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height)];
[leftButtonIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourButtonImageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButtonIcon addTarget:self.viewDeckController action:@selector(YourSelectorMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *leftbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButtonIcon];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftbtn];
```

Comment: This codes add just one button while question wants two button. one back button and a second button to the right of the back button.

Comment: In that case rather then setting the LeftBarButtonItem for the self.navigationItem you can set this button as the RightBarButtonItem

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *leftbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButtonIcon];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:leftbtn];

Comment: I have a searchbar and a action button in my rightbarbuttons and know want to add a button that navigate user to another page to the let side near the back button

Comment: In that case you can add two buttons as a Subview on to a third button   add different selectorTarget to both the added as subviews and add the main button (on which both buttons are added) as the LeftBarButtonItem to self.navigationItem . This will resolve your problem

Comment: navigation item have attribute by name LeftButtonItems takes two button item forleft button items. By this attribute we can add two button. But the problem is that how the back button that i add have the same shape by the back button that navigation bar itself adds in my other pages. I want they be same in all pages and like the arrow that apple by default set.